# Javascript +/+= Operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with a basic movement engine I have made, where the *Up key* triggers a function making a small `div` go up, and the *Down key* doing the opposite. I am fairly sure it's to do with the `+=` in the `Down()` function, and I have tested it with `-=`, which works fine, just I can't work out what might be clashing with the function.

At the bottom, I have put a comment to indicate where my problem is.

```js
    var interval = '';
    var key = false;
    var interval1 = '';
    var key1 = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 38) {
        if(key === false){
            interval = setInterval(function(){Up()},20)
        key = true;
        }
    }
    if(e.which === 40) {
        if(key1 === false){
            interval1 = setInterval(function(){Down()},20)
        key1 = true;
        }
    }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 38) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        key = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 40) {
        clearInterval(interval1)
        key1 = false;
    }
    });

    document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = '46%';

    var Top = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
    var Topp = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);

    function Up(){
 if(Top > 0){
  Top = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
     Top -= 0.2;
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = Top+'%';
    }
    }

    function Down(){
 if(Topp > 0){
  Topp = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
     Topp += 0.2;                             //<--PROBLEM
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = Topp+'%';
    }
    }
```

```css
#Jumper{
 position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 48%;
    height: 8%;
    width: 4%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='Jumper'></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this?

Here is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/Tobsta/2gnoq5hx/

Comment: `parseInt` won't work a) because you're using it wrong (add a base, e.g. `parseInt(string, 10)` and b) because your string is probably in the wrong format.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I know how to use parseInt, but what do you mean by my string being in the wrong format?

Comment: `parseInt()` returns an integer, as the name suggests. If you add only 0.2 to the value it will always round it down and undo the previous change (e.g. 10 + 0.2 = 10.2, `parseInt(10.2)` = 10).

Comment: The reason why it looks like it works with `Up()` is that in practice it takes away 1 instead of 0.2 (e.g. 10 - 0.2 = 9.8, `parseInt(9.8)` = 9).

Comment: @Juhana I've only tried parseInt() on Down() because the + string operator seems to turn the Topp variable into a string. And Up() takes away 0.2, not 1

Comment: @Juhana Thanks anyway. At least I know not to use parseInt to fix it

Comment: I don't understand why you even retrieve the value from the element's style when you already store it neatly in a variable. https://jsfiddle.net/2gnoq5hx/1/

Comment: Sorry about the fuss guys, turns out Juhana was right about it incrementing by 1% at a time in Up(), though I don't get how...

Comment: @Juhana turns out that was the problem. Thanks for your help, I've now made it capable of moving left and right as well - https://jsfiddle.net/Tobsta/2gnoq5hx/2/

Comment: @Tobsta If an answer helps you, it's good to accept it to show that. Click the check mark below the voting buttons on the answer.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, my problem was already fixed, and it wasn't to do with the parseInt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use parseFloat(), because parseInt returns integer ::

```js
Topp = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gnoq5hx/3/

Answer (score 0):

It was this line that stuffed it all up:

```
Topp = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
```

Thanks Juhana for pointing that out.

Here's the working thing:

```js
var interval = '';
var key = false;
var interval1 = '';
var key1 = false;
var interval2 = '';
var key2 = false;
var interval3 = '';
var key3 = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 38) {
        if(key === false){
            interval = setInterval(function(){Up()},20)
        key = true;
        }
    }
    if(e.which === 40) {
        if(key1 === false){
            interval1 = setInterval(function(){Down()},20)
        key1 = true;
        }
    }
    if(e.which === 37) {
        if(key2 === false){
            interval2 = setInterval(function(){Left()},20)
        key2 = true;
        }
    }
    if(e.which === 39) {
        if(key3 === false){
            interval3 = setInterval(function(){Right()},20)
        key3 = true;
        }
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 38) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        key = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 40) {
        clearInterval(interval1)
        key1 = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 37) {
        clearInterval(interval2)
        key2 = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 39) {
        clearInterval(interval3)
        key3 = false;
    }
});

document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = '46%';
document.getElementById('Jumper').style.left = '48%';

var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('Jumper').style.left);

function Up(){
 if(a > 0){
     a -= 1;
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = a+'%';
    }
}

function Down(){
    if(a < 92){
  a += 1;
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.top = a+'%';
    }
}

function Left(){
 if(b > 0){
     b -= 0.5;
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.left = b+'%';
    }
}

function Right(){
    if(b < 96){
  b += 0.5;
     document.getElementById('Jumper').style.left = b+'%';
    }
}
```

```css
#Jumper{
 position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 48%;
    height: 8%;
    width: 4%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='Jumper'></div>
```

Or the js fiddle

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Tobsta/2gnoq5hx/2